# Jenkins Build successful even after PS script failed to execute

Tags: powershell, jenkins

I am executing Jenkins Job which Builds my .csproj file and execute few PS scripts.
Issue is I get a successful email even if my PS script fails,How should I tell my Jenkins Job to trigger me an email also if PS script is failing.

Error Logs-

```
Copy-Item : The process cannot access the file 
'\\10.0.1.190\d$\Build\RPC\abcde.RPC.AirSearch\Common.Logging.Core.dll' because it is being used by another process.
At C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\hudson9059014122834846757.ps1:3 char:1
+ Copy-Item "C:\AirSearchBnd\src\abcde.Air.Search.RPC.Host\bin\Release\*" "\\$en ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Copy-Item], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.IO.IOException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyItemCommand
 


[AirSearchBnd] $ powershell.exe -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy ByPass "& 'C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\hudson9149103993066004448.ps1'"
[SC] CreateService SUCCESS

SERVICE_NAME: AirSearchWindowsService 
        TYPE               : 10  WIN32_OWN_PROCESS  
        STATE              : 2  START_PENDING 
                                (STOPPABLE, NOT_PAUSABLE, ACCEPTS_SHUTDOWN)
        WIN32_EXIT_CODE    : 0  (0x0)
        SERVICE_EXIT_CODE  : 0  (0x0)
        CHECKPOINT         : 0x0
        WAIT_HINT          : 0x0
        PID                : 13784
        FLAGS              : 
 > C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe tag -l RPCBUILD_6 # timeout=10
 > C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe tag -a -f -m Jenkins Git plugin tagging with RPCBUILD_6 RPCBUILD_6 # timeout=10
Pushing tag RPCBUILD_6 to repo Dev
 > C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe --version # timeout=10
using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials 
 > C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe push https://github.com/abcdeHoldings/abcde.Services.Air.Search.git RPCBUILD_6
Email was triggered for: Always
Sending email for trigger: Always
Request made to compress build log
Sending email to: abcde@software.com abcde@software.com abcde@software.com abcde@software.com
Finished: SUCCESS
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is to configure Jenkins to send e-mails on failed builds and in the Powershell step add the following at the end:

```
if ($error) { exit 1 }
```

The problem with Jenkins Powershell plugin is that it doesn't honor the errors that happen in Powershell, only the exit code of the shell itself, this will force build to fail and trigger the email.

Answer (score 0):

There is an option of "Attaching Build Log". You can read the build log to see, if the ps script has failed.

Comment: Do I have any other alternate solution other than this as I have already set this up.

Comment: this is not the answer to the question. @Bhave check my answer, it should help